# Ubuntu Server 16.04 / Apache issue

Tags: apache2

I've got a really weird issue that's bugging me - been tearing my hair out all evening over this so I thought I'd put it out there overnight to see if I can get an answer.

I'm trying to reinstall Apache on a Ubuntu Server 16.4 box, using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

It was previously installed, but removed.

It appears to install OK, however the service will not start.

A cursory glance in `/etc/apache2` tells me why - there is a directory structure there, involving the usual suite of directories (eg. conf-available, conf-enabled, etc.) but there are actually no config files to speak of at all.

I've tried removing the package, clearing the package cache using sudo apt-get clean, done sudo apt-get autoremove to no avial.  I"m sure there's something really simple I'm getting wrong.

```
blanked@blanked:/etc/apache2$ service apache2 start

==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===

Authentication is required to start 'apache2.service'.

Authenticating as: ,,, (blanked)

Password:

==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===

This is the contents of the /etc/apache2 directory.

blanked@blanked:/etc/apache2$ ls -l

total 32

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 31 08:43 conf-available

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 15 11:33 conf-enabled

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Aug 31 08:43 mods-available

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 15 11:33 mods-enabled

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 31 08:43 sites-available

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 15 11:33 sites-enabled
```

Comment: Are you using 16.10 or 16.04? Your question says both. Also, the error you get for the service would be helpful.

Comment: Aaah sorry, that should be 16.04 :)  Getting a bit tired and frustrated.

Comment: This is what I get when I try and do a service start.

blanked@blanked:/etc/apache2$ service apache2 start
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'apache2.service'.
Authenticating as: ,,, (blanked)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===

Comment: This is the contents of the /etc/apache2 directory.

blanked@blanked:/etc/apache2$ ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 31 08:43 conf-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 15 11:33 conf-enabled
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Aug 31 08:43 mods-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 15 11:33 mods-enabled
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Aug 31 08:43 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 15 11:33 sites-enabled

Comment: Can you [edit] that into your question?

Comment: Also, that service start message doesn't seem to have any errors.

Comment: Try to purge instead. To do that, run the command `sudo apt autoremove --purge apache2` and then install apache2 again with `sudo apt install apache2`.

Comment: @Thanos Apostolou Thanks - I think you've just saved me a lot of hair!  That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I created an answer so that we can close this topic. As it turned out, some configuration files were missing or were faulty. So the solution was to purge apache2 by runinng `sudo apt autoremove --purge apache2` and then install apache2 again with `sudo apt install apache2`.

Remember that `sudo apt purge PACKAGE` removes the configuration files. The `sudo apt clean` command just deletes the downloaded .deb files so that you can gain some disk space.